# User input not reflected properly in AJAX URL call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to use user's city input (ex. Los Angeles) and include in Ajax URL parameters, however when I `console.log(searchURL)`. It doesn't add a `'+'` between `"los angels"` thus breaking the URL. What can be done to make the URL include the `+` between cities with two words.

```
var apiKey = "&client_id=OTU3MDMwMHwxNTEwMjUwNDQ0LjI3"
var baseQueryURL = "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?" + apiKey;
console.log(baseQueryURL);

function runSearch(queryURL) {
  $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      };

      $("#submitSearch").on("click", function(event) {
        //prevents default event from occuring
        event.preventDefault();

        userCity = $("#userCity").val();
        console.log(userCity);
        //create variable queryCity to hold city queried with URL parameters
        var queryCity = "&venue.city=" + userCity;
        //create searchURL to pass in as queryURL in AJAX call
        searchURL = searchURL + queryCity;
        console.log(searchURL);
        runSearch(searchURL);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[URL-encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the value:

```
userCity = encodeURIComponent($("#userCity").val());
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used this:

`userCity.split(" ").join("+")`